# Replace for loop with forEach for array of strings

Tags: javascript

I have below code to concatenate 2 strings. How can I use forEach on this case to replace the for loop in javascript?

```js
for(i = 0; i < values.caLocalCounterparty.length; i++)
{
    selectedProvinces =
        selectedProvinces.concat(values.caLocalCounterparty[i]).concat(";");
}
```

I tried replacing this with below but does not work. What am i doing wrong?

```js
selectedProvinces = values.caLocalCounterparty.forEach(a =>
    { selectedProvinces.concat(a).concat(";") });
```

Comment: You want reduce, not forEach

Comment: Why does it need to be a `forEach`? Can't you just use `selectedProvinces = values.caLocalCounterparty.join(';')`?

Comment: u don't need foreach. And your code is not clear. It has syntax error. But we got the point anyway.

Comment: @Ivar has the best answer, it work in all relevant browser and is quite possibly the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning selectedProvinces  inside the forEach loop

```
values.caLocalCounterparty.forEach(a=> { 
selectedProvinces = selectedProvinces.concat(a).concat(";")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:** There is no return value for ForEach, hence below code is not working

```
selectedProvinces = values.caLocalCounterparty.forEach(a =>
    { selectedProvinces.concat(a).concat(";") });
```

To resolve this issue, use below options

**Option1 :** Replace forEach with map , as map returns array and assigns to selectedProvinces

```
selectedProvinces = values.caLocalCounterparty.map(a =>
        { selectedProvinces.concat(a).concat(";") });
```

**Option2:** Using assignment part inside forEach loop

```
values.caLocalCounterparty.forEach(a =>
        { selectedProvinces = selectedProvinces.concat(a).concat(";") });
```